# Having problems with file_put_contents syntax when using multiple variables

Tags: php

I tried this:

```
file_put_contents("logs/login.log", "$date: ".$userow['UserName'] ($userow['GBS'])" logged in.".PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

But I get this error:

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '&quot; logged in.&quot;' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)
```

I don't see what the problem is, there are 4 `"` in what to put in the login.log, and the syntax appears correct in text editors. I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any concatenation operators at all, except to add your constant. A [double quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) will parse out your array indices quite nicely:

```
$logfile = "logs/login.log";
$msg = "$date: $userow[UserName] ($userow[GBS]) logged in." . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($logfile, $msg, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `.` in there.

```
file_put_contents("logs/login.log", "$date: ".$userow['UserName'] ($userow['GBS'])." logged in.".PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Edit:  I suspect you are also missing some other quotes in there, as this bit is probably not what you are looking for:

```
$userow['UserName'] ($userow['GBS'])
```

Edit 2: If I had to guess, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
file_put_contents("logs/login.log", "$date: ".$userow['UserName']. " (".$userow['GBS'].") logged in.".PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: That just gives me `Fatal error: Function name must be a string`.